# How to populate a Flutter dropdown box

Tags: flutter

How do I populate a Flutter Dropdown box?. I have the following key value pair data.

I want to show the user the value (name) and on click get the ID value

```
[
  {'Id': '1', 'Name': 'item 1'}
  { 'Id': '2', 'Name': 'item 2' }
  { 'Id': '3', 'Name': 'item 3' }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the map function against the list to generate what you need.

```
   final myMapList = [
      {'Id': '1', 'Name': 'item 1'},
      { 'Id': '2', 'Name': 'item 2' },
      { 'Id': '3', 'Name': 'item 3' },
    ];
    String _newValue = myMapList[0]['Id'];

    ...

    DropdownButton<String>(
                  value: _newValue,
                  onChanged: (String newValue) {
                    setState(() {
                      _newValue = newValue;
                    });
                  },
                  items: myMapList.map(
                          (Map item) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                          value: item['Id'],
                          child: Text(
                              item['Name'],
                        );
                      }).toList(),),
```